# Incorrect order of results in "IN" of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by, sql-in

I need help in ordering my resultset of SQL Server 2005. My Query is

```
Select RQuery from EPMaster where PName IN ('PFNAME','POName','PFSName');
```

The result shown is in order as stored in the table **EPMaster**

In the table **EPMaster**, the order for values of **PName** are:

```
PFName -> 1
PFSName -> 2
POName -> 3
```

1 being the topmost and 3 being lowest

I need the results in order of the passed parameters of the query made with `IN`. It means that the result should be in the form

```
PFName -> 1
POName -> 2
PFsName -> 3
```

Comment: Then stick an `order by PName` statement on the end. Particular ordering is never guaranteed unless you specify it - SQL Server is just designed to get you the rows back in the way it deems the fastest at the time.

Comment: `Order by` does not solves the issue. It can never give the results in the form in which I have passed the parameters. It can be either `ASC` or `DESC` but my parameters will be dynamic, as it'll be passed from a C# Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` does not guarantee *any* sort of order unless you specify an `order by` clause.

For your particular case, you can use something like:

```
... order by (case when PName = 'PFSName' then 'ZZZZZ' else PName end ) asc
```

but you should be aware that this sort of query may be a performance killer.

If your query is created dynamically, and you have no control over the order in which the possibilities are given, yet still want to dictate that the rows are in the same order, you may have to resort to building your query differently, such as with:

```
select 1 as xyzzy, RQuery from EPMaster where PName = 'PFNAME'
union all
select 2 as xyzzy, RQuery from EPMaster where PName = 'POName'
union all
select 3 as xyzzy, RQuery from EPMaster where PName = 'PFSName'
order by 1 asc
```

If your code builds *this* query rather than the `in` vesrsion, you *can* guarantee that the rows will be returned in the order as specified, because of the `xyzzy` column you add (and sort by).

Comment: I need to focus much on performance as well because, the parameters in `IN` can be any number.

Comment: @Cyberpks, you can't always get _everything_ you want, sometimes you have to do a trade-off :-) In any case, a decent DBMS will parallelise those queries since they're mutually exclusive. Don't know if SQL Server is that smart, I'm a DB2 man myself. In any case, you should benchmark this answer (and any others) against your worst-case table.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but are you sure that this will not make any issue if the number of `PName` parameter increases. Will it provide the same order and what about the performance.

Comment: Am I sure? Yes, 100% sure on the order (for the second code sample, not the first one), 80% sure on the performance. Will I guarantee that? Yes, if it doesn't, I'll return every dollar you paid me for the advice :-) In other words, no chance! That's why, for _any_ potential optimisation,  you should _measure, not guess!_ Create a single query that uses _every_ value of `PName` in an arbitrary order, then test both the functionality _and_ performance against a large enough table.

Comment: Ok Thanks friend. Don't take that seriously:). If you say that you are 100% sure, I'll try that out with my project and be back soon. You don't need to guarantee it. Really appreciate your help!!!.

Comment: Got the results as needed with a little changes in my codes. You were really helpful. **Now you don't need to pay every dollars that I paid you for the advice :D**, I've got the guarantee...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select RQuery from EPMaster 
where PName IN ('PFNAME','POName','PFSName')
order by case when PName = 'PFName'  then 0
              when PName = 'POName'  then 1
              when PName = 'PFsName' then 2
              else 999
         end asc
```

An alternative and often used solution is to add an OrderBy column to a FK lookup table (Pname).